# Extending a Kotlin class with a primary and secondary constructor

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to extend a class that has a primary and secondary constructors. The reason being, I want a private/protected primary constructor that has fields which are common between two secondary constructors. This works fine for the base class, but *extending* that class doesn't allow me to do that.

Here is an example of what I want to do:

```
abstract class A constructor(val value: Int) {

    var description: String? = null
    var precision: Float = 0f

    constructor(description: String, value: Int) : this(value) {
        this.description = description
    }

    constructor(precision: Float, value: Int) : this(value) {
        this.precision = precision
    }

    abstract fun foo()
}



class B(value: Int) : A(value) {
    // Compiler complains here: Primary constructor call expected.
    constructor(longDescription: String, value: Int) : super(longDescription, value)
    // Compiler complains here: Primary constructor call expected.
    constructor(morePrecision: Float, value: Int) : super(morePrecision, value)

    override fun foo() {
        // Do B stuff here.
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't allow you to do what? What's the error?

Comment: @TheWanderer I've added comments to show the error in-line.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your derived class `B` has a primary constructor `B(value: Int)`, so its secondary constructors must call the primary one using `this(...)` rather than `super(...)`.

This requirement is described here: [Constructors](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html#constructors)

To solve this, just remove the primary constructor from `B` together with its super constructor call, this will allow the secondary constructors to directly 
call the secondary constructors of the super class:

```
class B : A {
    constructor(longDescription: String, value: Int) : super(longDescription, value)
    constructor(morePrecision: Float, value: Int) : super(morePrecision, value)

    // ...
}
```

Comment: A would still need to be initialized with the primary constructor though, wouldn't it? (`class B : A(something)`)

Comment: @TheWanderer Since `B` has no primary constructor, it can't call the `A`'s constructor in the signature, so that call should be removed as well, `B(value: Int) : A(value)` → `B : A`. Instead, `B`'s secondary constructors should call one of the `A`'s constructors via `super(...)`.

Comment: @hotkey I thought I had tried this already, but you're right. This works. :)

Comment: Is there any way to call a secondary constructor of A from B in a situation like this: `class A(a, b)`, `class B(a, b):A(a, b)` ?